# Python iterate webelements and add to DF

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through web elements in a website to create a DataFrame with the elements with `/strong` as my keys, and the elements without `/strong` as my values.

How can i iterate through  the elements to create this dict?

The website:
https://ticker11.com.br/emissoes/

The elements:

```
First Key: //*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span[1]/strong
First Value: //*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span[2]/span

Second Key: //*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span[3]/strong
Second Value: //*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span[4]/span
```

With the code bellow, i scrape all of the `//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span` to a list, but thats not what i want.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

Fiis_Link = "https://ticker11.com.br/emissoes/"

driver.get(Fiis_Link)

xyz = []

for row in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('row-details-open'):
    row.click()
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span'):
        xyz.append(x.text)
        print(xyz)
```

output is a list of all the elements i need, but not organized the way i want the DF to be:

```
['Proporção de Sobras:', 'Não há', 'Liquidação dos Direitos:', 'Não há', 'Liquidação das Sobras:', 'Não há', 'Liquidação das Reservas:', '02.09.20', 'Data de Encerramento:', '08.09.20', 'Emissão:', '1ª', 'Oferta:', 'ICVM 400 (Oferta Pública)', 'Investimento Mínimo:', 'R$ 1.000,00 (100 cotas)', 'Captação Mínima:', 'Não há', 'Captação Máxima:', 'R$ 576.000.000,00', 'Coordenador Líder:', 'Banco J. Safra', 'Alocação/Rateio:', 'Proporcional', 'Documentação Oficial:', 'Prospecto Preliminar, Aviso ao Mercado', 'Observações:', '¹ Só é possível fazer pedidos múltiplos de 100.', 'Proporção de Sobras:' .......
```

Comment: Can you post sample output as well?

Comment: Just edited with the output i currentyle have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would store your different elements in 4 lists (I would create them within your for loop for exemple):

- `first_key`
- `first_value`
- `second_key`
- `second_value`

And then actually create the dataframe :

```py
dictionnary = {
   'first_key': first_key, 
   'first_value':first_value, 
   'second_key':second_key, 
   'second_value':second_value
}
xyz = pd.DataFrame(data=dictionnary)
```

Comment: This is not a solution because the number of key elements is unkown, i cant just map the keys because a new key may appear tomorrow.